# Removing rows from a collection changing types of the collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a two collections. First one is a big collection. Another one is remove list. For example:

```
$data= List::where('status', true)->get();

$list= List::where('begin_at', '<', Carbon::now())->pluck('id');

$result = $data->whereNotIn('id', $list);
```

This is just a simple example. I have a dynamic data. My question is:

When i return `$data`, it returns `[{}, {}, ...]` format

But when i return `$result`, it returns `{}, {}, ...`

I tried to `$result->toArray()`, `$result->toCollapse()` but none of them is worked.

Why after the `get()`, using where condition changing the type of the collection? Why array symbols gone? What is the best practices in here to solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not the answer you were looking for but you can actually get the same result modifying the first query alone. `$data= List::where('status', true)->where('begin_at', '>', Carbon::now())->get();`

Comment: @user3532758 yes. it will be work in a single query. 
Dear Ali Ozen, Why you made its complicated?! Any specific reason?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @KarthikSWOT . I just give some example. I can't change working codes right now. I am a small part on huge project. Just need to add extra eloquent query to returned query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `all()` on the collection to get it as an array with the Eloquent models intact. If you use `toArray()` instead, it will convert everything to an plain PHP array.

`$data->whereNotIn('id', $list)->all();`

[See docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-all)

Calling `get()` on a model will create a collection, and the collection upon creation will call `all()` on itself. So after modifying the collection you will need to call `all()` yourself to the the same "format" as from `get()`.

Comment: Still dunno why this doesn't work. But it doesn't. I am usualy adding ->all() to getting an array in like this cases. Probably i am missing something and didn't write on the question.